# Testing value of current footnote number

Tags: counters

How can I test the value of a counter? For instance, can I do
something like `\ifnum\counter{footnote}=1` (which doesn't work)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

and

```
\ifnumequal{\value{footnote}}{1}{commands if true}{commands if false}
```